# How to create a new column as a result of comparing two nested consecutive rows in the Panda dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, while-loop

I need to write a code in Panda Dataframe. So: The values in the ID column will be checked sequentially whether they are the same or not. Three situations arise here. Case 1: If the ID is not the same as the next line, write it as "unique" in the Comment column. Case 2: If the ID is the same as the next column and different from the next one, write it as "ring" in the Comment column. Case 3: If the ID is the same as the next multiple columns, write it as "multi" in the Comment column. Case 4: do this until the rows in the ID column are complete.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('History-s.csv')

a = len(df['ID'])
c = 0
while a != 0:
 c += 1
    while df['ID'][i] == df['ID'][i + 1]:
        if c == 2:
           if df['Nod 1'][i] == df['Nod 2'][i + 1]:
               df['Comment'][i] = "Ring"
               df['Comment'][i + 1] = "Ring"
          else:
               df['Comment'][i] = "Multi"
               df['Comment'][i + 1] = "Multi"
         elif c > 2:
             df['Comment'][i] = "Multi"
             df['Comment'][i + 1] = "Multi"
        i += 1
   else:
        df['Comment'][i] = "Unique"
```

a = a -1
print(df, '\n')

> Data is like this:
> [Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqZYG.png)
> After coding data frame should be like this:
> [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n33iZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the input dataframe you have provided, my first impression was that as you are checking **next** line in a while loop, so you are strictly considering just the next comin line, for ex.

| ID | value | comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | MULTI |
| 1 | 3 | RING |
| 3 | 4 | UNIQUE |

But if that is not the case, you can simply use pandas groupby function.

```
def func(df):
    if len(df)>2:
        df['comment'] = 'MULTI'
    elif len(df)==2:
        df['comment'] = 'RING'
    else:
        df['comment'] = 'UNIQUE'
    return df

df = df.groupby(['ID']).apply(func)
```

Output:

```
   ID   value   comment
0   1   2       RING
1   1   3       RING
2   3   4       UNIQUE
```